# How to hide an API key in the public folder of node.js when deploying to heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, heroku

I am serving public HTML and JavaScript files through the public folder of node.js with the help of `app.use(express.static('public'));` in my server.js file.

The public folder has an `index.js`. Here I have an api key for fetching a Map from mapbox. I added the api key into a `config.js` file within the public folder, and added config.js to the git ignore file inside the public folder.
This doesn't work when I deploy the code on heroku.

How do I successfully deploy the code on Heroku without leaking the Map API key present in the public folder of node.js? I know that API's need to be on the server side, but should I do the same for the map API?

Comment: Don't put it in the public folder or in the source, use an environment variable. If you're lucky, the API you're using may support [whitelisting domains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72105923) that your key may be used on, in which case it isn't that much of an issue if your key gets leaked

Answer (score 0):

npm install dotenv

create a .env file in your project

put API key there

In your server file initial dotenv dependencies

And use it where you want

On Heroku go to settings and reveal config vars and add your .env variable there with value and that would be it

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? How do I access the .env file from the public folder? Is the last step you mentioned the only thing that I need to do?

Comment: Check documentation of dotenv package

Comment: dotenv does not work on the client side public folders. It is only for the server side node.js